# Deserialize JSON object with unknown name

Tags: c#, json

I have json like this

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "response_code": 200,
    "message": "",
    "collection": { 
        "<channel_id>": {
              "<category_id>": {
                    "id_category": "<category_id>",
                    "name": "<category>",
                    "date_created": "<date_tagged>"
                     },
               "<category_id>": {
                    "id_category": "<category_id>",
                    "name": "<category>",
                    "date_created": "<date_tagged>"
                     }
               }
            }
}
```

which channel_id and category_id is not a fixed name. How do I can deserialize it on C#?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming everything else is pretty much fixed, you might try to model this along these lines:

```
public class MyJsonClass
    {
        public String Result { get; set; }
        public int Response_Code { get; set; }
        public String Message { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, JsonCategoryDescription>>
                  Collection { get; set; }
    }

    public class JsonCategoryDescription
    {
        public String Id_Category { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Date_Created { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you deserialize it as follows (`System.Web.Script.Serialization` namespace):

```
var result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyJsonClass>(myJsonString);
```

and you can access specific fields, like so:

```
result.Collection[SOME_CHANNEL_ID][SOME_CATEGORY_ID].Name = "XXX";
```

Comment: But what about channel_id? is channel_id not need to be written in the class?

Comment: If I'm reading the requirements correctly, channel_id is a placeholder, but might be any string. If that's correct (if it's not - disregard my answer completely), substitute the `SOME_CHANNEL_ID` bit with an actual string (same with `SOME_CATEGORY_ID`) and this will work.

Answer (score -1):

If you use Dynamic instead of a static type you can have a variable schema of your JSON file. Here is a working console program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText("file.json");

        dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(json);

        Console.WriteLine(obj.collection.channel_id);
    }
}
```